# Vertical Align Text In Bootstrap Nav Pills

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I have this:
http://jsfiddle.net/frankDraws/29tvLqzc/

I can't figure out how to vertically center/align the 2 lined text inside the `nav-pills`. I can center the single line of text but the double line is way off.

Btw, I need to keep all the `nav-pills` the same height.

```css
.top-bar,
.contain-to-grid {
 height: auto;
 margin: 20px auto 20px;
 background-color: transparent; }

/* Flipped Menu and Nav Pills */
.flipped-menu {
 margin:auto;
 height: auto;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
 transform: rotate(-180deg);
 -sand-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -ms-filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
 filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
}/* /end flipped menu */
#nav-welcome > span {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 0;
}
.nav-pills > li > a {
 border-radius: 0 !important;
 background-color: #8bbff3;
 color: #031831; /* #005b7f */
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 16px;
 box-shadow: 0 -1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 border: 0;
    height: 65px;
    width: 95%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);

}

 /* center's single copy text 

  
 */
.nav-pills > li > a:before {
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}/* end single line alignment */


.nav-pills > li.active > a, 
.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover {
 color:#fff!important;
 cursor:default;
 background-color:#00356B !important;
 border:0;
 border-bottom-color:transparent;
}
.nav-pills > li > a:hover: {
 border-radius:0;
 background:#00356B;
 color:#fff;
}
.navigation {
 margin-bottom:30px;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-right:-30px;
 
}
.navigation ul li {
 margin:0 7px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/nav.js"></script>
        <div class="row text-center navigation">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills flipped-menu nav-justified">
                <li id="nav-welcome"><a class="align" href="index.html"><span>WELCOME</span></a>
                </li>
                <li id="nav-map" class="active"><a href="map.html">MAP</a>
                </li>
                <li id="nav-annual-passes"><a href="annual-passes.html">ANNUAL<br>PASSES</a>
                </li>
                <li id="nav-tickets-express"><a href="#">TICKETS + EXPRESS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/5snh0zdb/

Comment: Yeah, but I forgot to mention that I need to keep the buttons all the same height.

Comment: then you need to make them tall enough to accomodate the two lines

Comment: If you need to have a fixed height and force to break for some cases, then you have to handle them in separate... My question is: why are you forcing the break for that case?

Comment: I'm forcing the break because that's how the designer has it in the comps.

Unless you think I shouldn't force the break.

@PatrickLC What do you mean by "handle them in separate?"

Comment: Since the other buttons doesn't have two lines (only have one line) and they have a fixed height, you could create some css class to handle the vertical position (ie: using padding) only for the two lines button.